# Unable to see the source of the problem with the code for sending data to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am very sorry to appear much ignorant but I have experienced this problem for long and I am now completely unable to understand why my JQuery function is not working.

I need this code to send data to PHP file which I am sure its working. I have tried to code everything with php but I have found there are place that I will have to include ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sending').on('submit', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            if(($('#receiver_id1').val() == '0') && ($('#receiver_id2').val() == '0') && ($('#receiver_id3').val() == '0'))
            {
                alert("Please fill in the recipient!");
                return false;
            }

            else if($.trim($("#message").val()) == '')
            {
                alert("You cannot send an empty message.");
                return false;
            }
            else if($('#subject').val() == '')
            {
                var retVal = confirm("Are you sure to send a message without a subject?");
                   if( retVal == true ) {
      var receiver_id1 = $('#receiver_id1').val();
      var receiver_id2 = $('#receiver_id2').val();
      var receiver_id3 = $('#receiver_id3').val();
      var receiver_name1 = $('#receiver_id1').text();
      var receiver_name2 = $('#receiver_id2').text();
      var receiver_name3 = $('#receiver_id3').text();
      var from_user_name =  '<?php echo $from_user_name;?>';
      var from_user_id =  '<?php echo $from_user_id;?>';
      var subject = $('#subject').val();
      var message = $('#message').val();
       $.ajax({
        url:"messaging.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{receiver_id1:receiver_id1, receiver_id2:receiver_id2, receiver_id3:receiver_id3, receiver_name1:receiver_name1, receiver_name2:receiver_name2, receiver_name3:receiver_name3, subject:subject, message:message},
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('#receiver_id1').val("0");
          $('#receiver_id2').val("0");
          $('#receiver_id3').val("0");
          $('#subject').val("");
          $('#message').val("");
               var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
               $.ajax({  
                    url:"select.php",  
                    type:"post",  
                    data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                    success:function(data){  
                         $('#employee_detail').html(data);  
                         $('#popup').modal("show");
                    }  
               });  
             },
             error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                 alert('Exception:', exception);
             }
                });

                   } else {
                      return false;
            }
        }        else
            {
      var receiver_id1 = $('#receiver_id1').val();
      var receiver_id2 = $('#receiver_id2').val();
      var receiver_id3 = $('#receiver_id3').val();
      var receiver_name1 = $('#receiver_id1').text();
      var receiver_name2 = $('#receiver_id2').text();
      var receiver_name3 = $('#receiver_id3').text();
      var from_user_name =  '<?php echo $from_user_name;?>';
      var from_user_id =  '<?php echo $from_user_id;?>';
      var subject = $('#subject').val();
      var message = $('#message').val();
       $.ajax({
        url:"messaging.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{receiver_id1:receiver_id1, receiver_id2:receiver_id2, receiver_id3:receiver_id3, receiver_name1:receiver_name1, receiver_name2:receiver_name2, receiver_name3:receiver_name3, from_user_name:from_user_name, from_user_id:from_user_id, subject:subject, message:message},
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('#receiver_id1').val("0");
          $('#receiver_id2').val("0");
          $('#receiver_id3').val("0");
          $('#subject').val("");
          $('#message').val("");
               var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
               $.ajax({  
                    url:"select.php",  
                    method:"post",  
                    data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                    success:function(data){  
                         $('#employee_detail').html(data);  
                         $('#popup').modal("show");
                    }  
               });  
             },
             error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                 alert('Exception:', exception);
             }
       });

            }
        });

    });
```

I really need help. I absolutely need this script to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no question here. How can we know what isn't working when we can't run this script? Add an error message of some sorts, at the very least.

Comment: Are you able to shrink this code down a little bit? This is why we ask for 'minimal' reproducible examples - just reading this requires significant effort.

Comment: Just narrowed down to the code that I think is not working.

Comment: When I run the code without the script by assigning variable in php to different values other than $_POST... , the code is working but when I add the script, there is no data that is sent.

Comment: Did you debug the script? are you getting any error or success?

Comment: I am getting success, but the php file is not receiving any data.

Comment: Which php file (messaging.php or select.php) is it not posting to? I see several issues with the code and there is just a lot of stuff going on here.

Comment: messaging.php file

Comment: @nawed, I can really appreciate your help. I also don't understand. Thanks

Comment: All you are not getting is the employee_id, right?

Comment: Yes @Nawed Khan